# Partitioning observables in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm looking for some way of splitting an observable sequence into separate sequences that I can process independently based on a given predicate. Something like this would be ideal:

```
var (evens, odds) = observable.Partition(x => x % 2 == 0);
var strings = evens.Select(x => x.ToString());
var floats = odds.Select(x => x / 2.0);
```

The closest I've been able to come up with is doing two `where` filters, but that requires evaluating the condition and processing the source sequence twice, which I'm not wild about.

```
observable = observable.Publish().RefCount();
var strings = observable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => x.ToString());
var floats = observable.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).Select(x => x / 2.0);
```

F# seems to have good support for this with [Observable.partition<'T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/observable.partition%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) and [Observable.split<'T,'U1,'U2>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/observable.split%5B%27t,%27u1,%27u2%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), but I've not been able to find anything equivalent for C#.

Comment: you can always pull in the F# library and use it from C#

Comment: Looking at the F# source code it looks like it does actually just apply two filters to the source stream so it's basically the same as my proposal with two `wheres`.

Comment: The two links are dead, and I can't find suitable replacement links.

Answer (score 2):

A `GroupBy` may remove the "observe twice" restriction, though you'll still end up with `Where` clauses:

```
public static class X
{
    public static (IObservable<T> trues, IObservable<T> falsies) Partition<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> partitioner)
    {
        var x = source.GroupBy(partitioner).Publish().RefCount();
        var trues = x.Where(g => g.Key == true).Merge();
        var falsies = x.Where(g => g.Key == false).Merge();
        return (trues, falsies);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I figured I might be able to do something with `GroupBy` but the `Merge` was the step I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Oh actually it looks like the source sequence does get evaluated twice when you do that. Damn

Comment: Oops, lazy of me. Updated code: Var x should be Published+Refcounted. The advantage remains that if your filter function is expensive, that is only run once.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that subscribing to the `trues` warms automatically the `source` observable, making it possible that the `IGroupedObservable<false, T>` will be emitted before the subscription to the `falsies` observable. In this case the `falsies` will never emit any elements. You could alleviate this problem by replacing the `.Publish()` with `.Replay()`, but even so you may still lose some `falsies`, that may be emitted synchronously during the subscription to the `trues`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
var (odds,evens) = (collection.Where(a=> a % 2 == 1), collection.Where(a=> a % 2 == 0));?
```

or if you want to partition based on one condition

```
Func<int,bool> predicate = a => a%2==0;

var (odds,evens) = (collection.Where(a=> !predicate(a)), collection.Where(a=> predicate(a)));
```

I think there is no working around the fact that you iterate the items twice this way, what else could be done would be to have a method that accepts a predicate and pass in the 2 sepatate collections and populate them in one iteration in a foreach or for.

Something like this:

```
var collection = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

Func<int,bool> predicate = a => a%2==0;
var odds = new List<int>();
var evens = new List<int>();

Action<List<int>, List<int>, Func<int, bool>> partition = (collection1, collection2, pred) =>
{
    foreach (int element in collection)
    {
        if (pred(element))
        {
            collection1.Add(element);
        }
        else 
        {
            collection2.Add(element);
        }
    }
};

partition(evens, odds, predicate);
```

Expanding on the last idea, are you looking for something like this?

```
public static (ObservableCollection<T>, ObservableCollection<T>) Partition<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var collection1 = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    var collection2 = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    foreach (T element in collection)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            collection1.Add(element);
        }
        else
        {
            collection2.Add(element);
        }
    }

    return (collection1, collection2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Your proposal with the `ObservableCollection` is along the right lines, but I'm dealing with observable sequences (`IObservable`) rather than collections, so it needs to return the new sequences immediately because they might be infinite sequences. I've cooked something up which creates a pair of `Subject`s, but it's kind of big and I was hoping for something pre-existing.

Comment: Hmm nothing comes to mind right now that would 'yield' in real time in a tuple, maybe instead of creating them inside the method, pass the IObservables in and intercept the calls when those sequences change.

Answer (score 0):

Warming the source sequence by using the `RefCount` operator is not a good idea, because the source sequence may start emitting elements before all subscriptions to derived sequences are in place. In that case some of the emitted elements could be lost. A safer approach is to postpone warming the source sequence until all observers have been subscribed. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
var published = observable.Publish(); // Make sure not to warm it too early

var strings = published.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => x.ToString());
var floats = published.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).Select(x => x / 2.0);

strings.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
floats.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

published.Connect(); // Now that all subscriptions are in place, it's time to warm it

await published; // Wait for the completion of the source sequence
```

You could make the above code a bit less repetitive by using the `LookupObservable<TSource, TKey>` class, that is included in [an answer of a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958608/rx-multi-consumers-by-key-subscription-complexity/65056244#65056244). This class was implemented because creating multiple `Where` subsequences can be quite inefficient, in case the total number of subsequences is large (because each element emitted by the source will be checked for numerous conditions). In your case you have only two subsequences, one for the key `true` and one for the key `false`, so using the `LookupObservable` class is less compelling. In any case, here is a usage example:

```
var published = observable.Publish(); // Make sure not to warm it too early

var lookup = new LookupObservable<int, bool>(published, x => x % 2 == 0);

var strings = lookup[true].Select(x => x.ToString());
var floats = lookup[false].Select(x => x / 2.0);

strings.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
floats.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

published.Connect(); // Now that all subscriptions are in place, it's time to warm it

await published; // Wait for the completion of the source sequence
```