# RX - Multi consumers by key subscription complexity

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I got an `observable` of `KeyValuePair<int,double>`:

```
--(7|45.2)--(3|11.1)--(5|13.2)--(6|36.2)--(3|57.4)
```

I got a list of consumers defined at runtime.
They are only interested in values produced for a single key (*myKey*).

For example:

- the consumer 7, is only interested in the value 45.2.
- the consumer 3, is only interested in the values 11.1 and 57.4
- the consumer 1, is only interested in values with myKey = 1, so none
  here.

Here is my consumer subscription code (one per consumer):

```
myObservable.Where(t => t.Key == myKey).Subscribe(t => /* DoSomething*/);
```

Let's take:

- N = number of messages being produced by `myObservable`
- M = number of consumers

Let's call Comparison the code `t.Key == myKey`

For every new message being published, Comparison will be executed M times (once per consumer).
In the case of N messages, Comparison will be executed N * M

**Is RX Extension offering another way to do to avoid executing that many comparisons?**

Do I need to make it myself? (using the dictionary of (mykey, consumers) for example, and forwarding the messages to the right consumer(s))

Thanks

Comment: You could avoid the dictionary with a `GroupBy` and each subscribers is only subscribing to the group their interested in.

Comment: Not sure how I could do :"each subscribers is only subscribing to the group their interested in"?

Comment: Maybe something along these lines `source.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(grp => grp.Subscribe(kvp => /*each group do something*/));`

Comment: JSteward you are right, if I apply a `.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)` on myObservable and the consumer do: `myObservable.Where(gp => gp.Key == myKey).SelectMany(gp=>gp).Select(kvp=>kvp.Value).Subscribe(v => /* DoSomething*/)` it will give a different result.
The complexity of this code, if I take K = the number of myKey possible (myKey in the [1...K] interval), will now be at worst K * M times. As for any new myKey an observable will be created and pushed through every new consumer that will execute the comparison on it. Do you agree on it?

Comment: Yes, I think I'm following you. The comparison will happen once per group per subscriber. There's of course other measures of complexity for that code but this would seem to lessen the number of key comparisons.

Comment: A little optimization:
`myObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(gp => gp.Key == myKey).SelectMany(gp=>gp??Observable.Default<KeyValuePair<int, double>>()).Select(kvp=>kvp.Value).Subscribe(v => /* DoSomething*/)`

It ends up being quite complex, I am sure there might be a better way?

Comment: I think there is no out of the box way to solve it as this question ask for a Pull approach of change propagation, whereas RX is meant to use a Push approach. 
As in https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Reactive_programming#Change_propagation_algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to optimize this setup:

```
IObservable<KeyValuePair<int, double>> myObservable;

myObservable.Where(e => e.Key == 1).Select(e => e.Value).Subscribe(x => { /* DoSomething*/ });
myObservable.Where(e => e.Key == 3).Select(e => e.Value).Subscribe(x => { /* DoSomething*/ });
myObservable.Where(e => e.Key == 7).Select(e => e.Value).Subscribe(x => { /* DoSomething*/ });
```

This setup will indeed cause multiple comparisons for each element emitted by the `myObservable`. A simple way to optimize it is to group the `myObservable` with the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh212069(v=vs.103)) operator, in order to created a nested observable structure:

```
IObservable<IGroupedObservable<int, double>> myGroupedObservable = myObservable
    .GroupBy(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

...and then select the group that you want to observe, and [`Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211658(v=vs.103)) the nested structure to a flat sequence:

```
myGroupedObservable.Where(g => g.Key == 1).Merge().Subscribe(x => { /* DoSomething*/ });
myGroupedObservable.Where(g => g.Key == 3).Merge().Subscribe(x => { /* DoSomething*/ });
myGroupedObservable.Where(g => g.Key == 7).Merge().Subscribe(x => { /* DoSomething*/ });
```

This way the comparison will occur only once per key and consumer. You are now comparing `IGroupedObservable<int, double>` subsequences, not `KeyValuePair<int, double>` elements. These subsequences are emitted by the `GroupBy` operator only when it receives the first element that has a distinct key. So the total number of comparisons will be equal to NxM, where N is the number of consumers and M is the number of the distinct keys. Unless you are dealing with millions of consumers, this number should be fairly small, and should not cause noticeable overhead.

A more complex approach that is based on a combination of the `GroupBy` operator and a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Subject<TSource>>`, can be found in the [5th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65056244/5) of this answer. It is probably less efficient than the simple approach above, because there are two dictionaries involved (the `GroupBy` also uses a dictionary internally), so each key is hashed twice.

Comment: @PiPo I updated the answer with a simpler approach.

Comment: Theodor, what you think of the implementation at the link below? It is a variant of your 5th implementation where we rely only on Rx GroupBy dictionary
https://github.com/plop44/ObservableLookup/blob/main/ObservableLookup/ObservableLookup.cs

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a go:

```
var subject = new Subject<KeyValuePair<int, double>>();

var interests = new Dictionary<int, Func<double, string>>()
{
    { 7, v => $"Seven:{v}" },
    { 3, v => $"Three:{v}" },
    { 1, v => $"One:{v}" },
};

IDisposable subscription =
    subject
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
        .Select(gx =>
            interests.ContainsKey(gx.Key)
            ? gx.Select(x => interests[gx.Key](x))
            : Observable.Empty<string>())
        .Merge()
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

When I test with this code:

```
subject.OnNext(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(7, 45.2));
subject.OnNext(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(3, 11.1));
subject.OnNext(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(5, 13.2));
subject.OnNext(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(6, 36.2));
subject.OnNext(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(3, 57.4));
```

I get this output:

```
Seven:45.2
Three:11.1
Three:57.4
```

The comparison is done once per key.